# Alert message in browser using Ajax based on Node JS response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I developed a simple form where a user can enter an author name. The name will be queried using Node JS in the database to check if there are tweets written by this author or not. If there is no data, I want to response to the client using Ajax by showing an alert.

This is the client side:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                error: function(error){
                    if(error.responseText == 'showAlert'){
                        alert("Please enter correct user name and password.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/process_post" method="POST">
        <select name="SearchTypes">
            <option value="Author" selected>Author</option>
            <option value="Mention">Mention</option>
            <option value="Tag">Tag</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="term">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the part of the Node JS that includes the response:

```
var query = connection.query(queryString, [term,term], function(err, rows) {
        console.log(rows);
        var tweet = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
        if (tweet.length == 0){
            res.status(500).send('showAlert');
        }else{
            for(var i in tweet){
            res.write("Author: ");
......
```

As you see, I used `res.status(500).send('showAlert');` to send the response to the client side but what really happens is that when I provide an input that does not have any data in the database (tweet length is zero), it just prints `showAlert` in the HTML page.

Comment: Where is the print code?Its not clear what you want say

Comment: @Nasser Has anything helped solve your problem?

Comment: @csum not yet actually

Answer (score 0):

That's because the above JavaScript runs the control only if there is an error, but your message is sent as a correct response. You should change your client code to check in case of success, like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            error: function(error){
                if(error.responseText == 'showAlert'){
                    alert("Please enter correct user name and password.");
            success: function(result){
                      if (result.responseText == 'showAlert'){
                            alert("There was an error")
                      }else{
                          //Do things...
                      }
                     }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't sending a status of 500 constitute an error in calls to `$.ajax`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap the ajax call in a form submit handler. Right now, when you submit the form, it is doing a full synchronous request and coming back with the text "showAlert".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      // keep the form from submitting synchronously
      e.preventDefault();

      var $form = $(e.currentTarget);

      // submit via ajax
      $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        method: $form.attr('method'),
        data: $form.serialize()
      })
      .done(function (response) {
        console.log('done: ', arguments);
      })
      .fail(function(error){
        console.log('failed: ', arguments);
        if(error.responseText == 'showAlert'){
          alert("Please enter correct user name and password.");
        }
      })
    });
});
```

Remove those calls to `console.log` once you have it working as you need. See [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for options in that call.

You will probably also want to give your `form` an id and then refer to it that way, e.g. `$('#myForm')`, so that you can add more forms to the page without causing any problems.